# Composer not downloading Magento2 from Magento repository

Tags: composer-php, magento2

I'm trying to install Magento 2 on my local server, but when I run the command in Composer ( composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/magento/project-community-edition) it stops at this message and too show an error.

```
    - Downloading magento/framework (103.0.3-p1)
  - Downloading magento/module-catalog (104.0.3-p1)
  - Downloading magento/module-page-builder (2.2.1-p1)
  - Downloading magento/magento2-base (2.4.3-p1)
 1/4 [=======>--------------------]  25%  - Downloading magento/framework (103.0.3-p1)
A connection timeout was encountered. If you intend to run Composer without connecting to the internet, run the command again prefixed with COMPOSER_DISABLE_NETWORK=1 to make Composer run in offline mode.
  - Downloading magento/module-page-builder (2.2.1-p1)
  - Downloading magento/magento2-base (2.4.3-p1)
 3/4 [=====================>------]  75%  - Downloading magento/magento2-base (2.4.3-p1)
  - Downloading magento/magento2-base (2.4.3-p1)
```

Then it continues the process, but it's like the internet speed is slow, because it takes a long time for each download, but the speed is normal.

The process ended with a Timeout error.

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  curl error 28 while downloading https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/magento2-base/magento-magento2-base-2.4.3
  .0-patch1.zip: Operation timed out after 300000 milliseconds with 12913299 out of 37568572 bytes received
```

Comment: "A connection timeout was encountered" - looks like a network issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my LAN, when restarting some equipment it started working again.

Comment: hi @Lucas, how do you fix your LAN issue ? 
I'm also facing this issue ... can not download module Magento/magento-base :((

Comment: Updating and rebooting my routers.